# More efficient way to create parallax fixed background image in css

Tags: css, animation, background-image, css-animations

We all know that background-attachment: fixed makes the background fixed and creates a parallax effect. However, this is extremely expensive, since the DOM has to repaint every time you scroll on the page. This makes your site feel a bit choppy, especially if you have several fixed backgrounds on your page. Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[This pure CSS example](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) uses absolute positioning, `transform`, and `perspective` to render the parallax effect. For some browsers, `scroll-behavior: smooth` may also minimize some of the visible choppiness.

There are more efficient ways to render a parallax effect by using JavaScript by animating only the visible elements and using intervals to update element positions. [This article](https://medium.com/@dhg/parallax-done-right-82ced812e61c#.3jvfjpodj) explains some of those techniques in greater detail. The `requestAnimationFrame` function in particular allows the browser to execute the scroll animation on the next available repaint.